# Timer class moving a JLabel through the JFrame! Why JLabel text can not be variable?

Tags: java, swing, timer, jframe, jlabel

In the last secong and third line if I say

```
label.setText("x = ");
```

The label is moving perfectly but when I change it to

```
label.setText("x = "+ x);
```

it does not move. To be specific I want to see the width location of JLabel when it's moving by variable **x**!
Beside this I said `label.setBounds(x,(getHeight()/2),300,300);` which set the Y bound of the label to half of the frame size but it's not at the middle of frame? Any Idea?

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class myTiemr {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        TimeFrame frame = new TimeFrame();
    }
}

class TimeFrame extends JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int x = 0;
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Here is my label");
    public TimeFrame()
    {
        int d = 10;
        setTitle("My Frame");
        setSize(500,500);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        add(label);
        Timer time = new Timer(d,new TimerListener());
        time.start();       
        setVisible(true);
    }
    class TimerListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if(x>getWidth()){
                x=-100;
            }
            x+=1;
            label.setText("x = "+ x);
            //label.setText("x = ");
            label.setBounds(x,(getHeight()/2),300,300);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that `label.setText("x = "+ x)` causes the text to remain still but yet the line `label.setText("x = ")` causes the label to move across the frame is that `revalidate()` is called on the `JLabel`. This will cause the correct behavior applying the current layout manager's rules (namely `BorderLayout` in this case).

When the text *does not change*, `revalidate()` is never called.

As @Sébastien Le Callonnec suggested setting no layout on the frame will cause

```
label.setText("x = "+ x)
```

to move as desired.

Comment: what about calling {revalidate()} function every time to apply the correct behaviour to BorderLayout. I meant is there any way to move the label and keep the the layout?

Comment: No can do. The layout managers job is to manage positioning and the label implicitly calls `revalidate()`. You could keep one `JPanel` with a null layout for your label.

Answer (score 3):

In the `TimeFrame` constructor, add:

```
this.setLayout(null);
```

after `this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);`.

Comment: Thanks mate, it seems moving through the frame and the second problem also solved b changing it to    
label.setBounds(x,((getHeight()/2)-150),300,300);
Because the area of label was not dertermined.